# PHP processing page isn't working

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm attempting to make a login system, with page `login.php` and posting form action to `processlogin.php`

The system uses php/html and SQLite3.

The form works fine, the problem I have is when it actually redirects me to the `processlogin.php` page. I have a bunch of strings set up to output to show me where things are failing, the problem is that I don't even get the very first string on the page. I've been trying different hunches for over an hour now, and haven't gotten anywhere. The only thing I have found out, is that if I remove the entire 2nd if statement (Checking if post value `register` is set) I get the first output.

Here is my `processlogin.php` - if any other code is needed I would be more than happy to share it.

```
<?php

    session_start();

    class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
        function __construct() {
             $this->open('../db/tables.db');
        }
    }

    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
        echo "<p style='display:none;'>Opened database successfully</p>\n";
    }

    if(isSet($_POST['login'])) {
        echo "<p style='display:none;'>login posted</p>\n";
        $loginNameFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['loginname']);
        $passwordFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $ret = $db->query("SELECT * from Users WHERE LoginName='$loginNameFromPost' LIMIT 1;");
        while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
            $hashedPasswordFromDB = $row['Password'];
            $levelFromDB = $row['Level'];
            $usernameFromDB = $row['DisplayName'];
        }

        if (password_verify($passwordFromPost, $hashedPasswordFromDB)) {
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $usernameFromDB;
            $_SESSION['Level'] = $levelFromDB;
            echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../index.php\">";
        } else {
            echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../login.php?err=1\">";
        }

    }

    if(isSet($_POST['register'])) {
        echo "<p style='display:none;'>register posted</p>\n";
        $loginNameFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['loginname']);
        $passwordFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $emailFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $displayNameFromPost = sqlite_escape_string($_POST['displayname']);

        $options = [
            'cost' => 11,
        ];

        $hash = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

        $sql ="INSERT INTO Users (uniqueID,DisplayName,LoginName,Level,Email,Password) VALUES (NULL,'$displayNameFromPost', '$loginNameFromPost',   '0', '$emailFromPost',  '$hash');"
        $ret = $db->exec($sql);
        if(!$ret){
            echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
            echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../login.php?err=2\">";
        } else {
          echo "Successfully registered\n";
          echo "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../login.php?msg=1\">";
        }

    }

?>
```

A side note: after a while I ran my code through `PHP Code Checker`, and it said `$ret = $db->exec($sql);` (pointing directly at the one inside the 2nd `if) which makes no sense to me, that code is needed!

Comment: `if(isSet($_POST['register']))` - `isSet` should be `isset` and that `if` should probably be an `elseif` ... at a quick glance

Comment: @CD001 Is there a difference between isSet and isset?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Not really.. But most people using `isset` in all lowercase.

Comment: @C0dekid.php That's what I thought. I also don't think it matters that they are both "If" statements, as they are handled independently.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton No, if you have two different submit buttons with both a different name and also different `if` statements, it can't be go wrong (mostly), mabye there is a little typo in your script.

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yes they are different submit buttons, in fact, neither of them ever show at the same time. My first thought was that I missed a semicolon somewhere but I can't find any.

Comment: Are you looking at the results in the page source? Just wandering why you have `<p style='display:none;'>` everywhere

Comment: @andrew Yeah, I'm using firebug to look at the source. I wasn't sure how to print to console from php, and didn't bother looking it up 3:

Comment: Is there any error you get? Parse errors etc.?? Place this on top to ensure there are no PHP errors: `ini_set("display_errors", "on"); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @C0dekid.php `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ret' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/paragon1/public_html/*PRIVATE*/trg/newrc/db/processlogin.php on line 54`

Comment: @C0dekid.php No, I'm declaring the $ret variable on that line.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Small typo, you forget the `;` at the end on line **53** :P

Comment: @C0dekid.php My goodness, what did I say? `My first thought was that I missed a semicolon somewhere`

Comment: What what, it's fixed now? Haha @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yes, that did it. I hate missing small things like that so many times. Now I just gotta figure out why I'm getting `Call to undefined function sqlite_escape_string()` -.- Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! I know such those small things that will explode your whole system though, glad it solved now :-) Shall I post it as answer? :$ @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yes please, expose my mistake! But really, yes please post an answer :P

Comment: @C0dekid.php - I'm surprised to find `isSet` actually works tbh; working on *nix I'd assumed it would be case-sensitive.

Comment: @CD001 Yeah me too, I have tested with `If` too, seems to work haha

Comment: @C0dekid.php I think if I didn't know any code and I looked at isset, I would be confused, so that's why i prefer isSet :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yeah and there are two words in it `is` and `set` so it would be logical to use `isSet` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the semicolon `;` on line **53**

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO Users (uniqueID,DisplayName,LoginName,Level,Email,Password) VALUES (NULL,'$displayNameFromPost', '$loginNameFromPost',   '0', '$emailFromPost',  '$hash');";
```

Hope this helps!